# What does the get method do on dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to figure out what the `get()` method does.

```
def numbers_to_strings(argument):
switcher = {
    0: "zero",
    1: "one",
    2: "two",
}
return switcher.get(argument, "nothing")
```

-- What does this function do?

Comment: What is the result of this code?

Comment: Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

Comment: You can try `help(dict.get)`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic - what does the debugger indicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the key `argument` is in `switcher`, the `.get()` method returns the `value` for the key.

If the `key` is not in the `dictionary`, the method returns the optional "nothing".

```
def numbers_to_strings(argument):
    switcher = {0: "zero",
                1: "one",
                2: "two"}
    return switcher.get(argument, "nothing")
```

Calling the above function with a `key` that is in the dictionary:

```
>>> numbers_to_strings(0)
'zero'
```

And, calling the function with a `key` that is not in the dictionary:

```
>>> numbers_to_strings(3)
'nothing'
```

You could read about the method at [dict.get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a KeyError.